# How to transfer callback method to the ng-bootstrap modal (Angular 2+)?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to do primitive thing - transfer method save to my modal. I do it this way:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input [(ngModel)]="name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="save()">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>`
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;
  @Output() action; //Actually I can use @Input or nothing

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  save() {
    this.action(this.name)
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-component',
  templateUrl: 'src/modal-component.html',
  providers: [HttpClient]
})
export class NgbdModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private http: HttpClient) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    modalRef.componentInstance.action = this.save.bind(this); //bind!!!
  }

  save(name) {
    console.log(name)

    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users?page=1&per_page=10').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
}
```

It works but it doesn't look like the best way. I have to bind this for save method. It doesn't clear. Maybe there is better way?

http://plnkr.co/edit/lJH2KHCnZBtHYDtSbraU?p=preview

Comment: you just want to close the dialog after save button is clicked?

Comment: You could use `Arrow`-function instead: `modalRef.componentInstance.action = (name) => this.save(name);`

Comment: Do you mean maybe to transfer `this.name` to parent component? If yes, then use `@Output() action = new EventEmitter();` and then emit `this.name` like so: `this.action.emit(this.name);`.

Comment: @Faisal, no, I know how to do it. I want to find the best way to transfer external method to my popup

Comment: @Arg0n, it is good way. but it is the same like with bind - you have to know that you need to use some wrapper

Comment: @GregorDoroschenko, It looks like more angular way (angular team describes it in the documentation in the component interaction section). But you also have to know how to use this method (modalRef.componentInstance.action.subscribe). I hope typification will help me)

Comment: @tamtakoe See this Plnkr for how to use `EventEmitter` instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/a0JJa3iBRd3j9lkvRR1H?p=preview

Comment: @Arg0n, I updated my plank with EventEmitter http://plnkr.co/edit/lJH2KHCnZBtHYDtSbraU?p=preview
Unfortunately I can't understand if save method completed successfully and close popup after this(

Comment: @tamtakoe See updated Plnkr

Comment: @Arg0n, hmm... You use close method out of modal. It is OK if you use modal in one place. But if you have f.e. common confirm modal which you use in several places you have to use close method everywhere :-)

Comment: @tamtakoe So how would the modal know that the request being made from outside it was successful? If you want to close it either way, you could just put `this.activeModal.close()` in the `save` function of the modal component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152155/discussion-between-tamtakoe-and-arg0n).

Answer (score 5):

**1) Remove:**

`@Output() action; //Actually I can use @Input or nothing`

**2) Remove:**

`modalRef.componentInstance.action = this.save.bind(this); //bind!!!`

**3) Save function close this modal with a result** (name for you but you can use a form object)

```
save() {
    this.activeModal.close(name);
}
```

**4) Add a callback on caller:**

```
// close action is result
// dismiss action is reason
open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
                   this.save(result);
                 }, (reason) => {
                   console.log('Dismissed action: ' + reason);
                 });
} 

save(user) {
    console.log('save action: ' + user);
}
```

Comment: How can one pass a function from the parent component to the modal component? Say I want to keep the modal open after the user clicks OK. I'd like to pass a function that returns an observable, and subscribe to the callback function inside the modal component, disable the modal buttons, display a loading indicator, then close the modal and return the results. I can pass simple functions and invoke them from the modal, but can't figure out how to pass observable functions. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nexus, this is another subject, we should ask another different question please.

Comment: I don't think my question is different though. I can pass a Function to the modal and invoke it from the modal component. What I wanna do is, pass an Observable to the modal, subscribe to it in the modal component, and close the modal with the result. I haven't found any solutions yet, so I've made it work with event emitters.